# E-mail sempre cai na caixa de spam PHP

Tags: php, funções

Olá.

Sempre que envio um e-mail com a função `mail()` do PHP o e-mail chega na caixa de SPAM.

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Acredito que isso esteja ligado com o serviço de hospedagem que você usa. Já passei pelo mesmo problea, que acabou quando troquei a hospedagem. Não poderia ser esse o seu caso?

Comment: Eu uso o [PHP Mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer),  além de ser uma biblioteca rica, oferece muitos recursos ausentes na função mail.

Comment: o problema ta no IP do servidor, quando alguem faz spam e utiliza a mesma hospedagem que você, acaba "sujando" o ip. você precisa encontrar as empresas que colocam o IP na blacklist e pedir pra retirar, mas dificilmente eles fazem isso, só quando é servidor próprio e não compartilhado. hospedagens usam vps compartilhado. a segunda solução é encontrar outra hospedagem e se certificar disso antes.